# Makefile multiple commands in single recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a Makefile recipe which runs a Python script. However, before and after the script I want to write some information to the screen describing what is being done. I could put these print statements into the Python script but that's a workaround and I'd like to understand why this doesn't work. My Makefile looks like:

```
/data/interim/opt_smoothing.csv: $(shell find /data/raw/evi_data -type f) src/data/determine_optimal_smoothing.py
        $(info Determining optimal smoothing) && python src/data/determine_optimal_smoothing.py && $(info Optimal smoothing calculation complete)
```

I was under the impression that putting these `&&` would chain these commands together and have them execute one after each other, but this doesn't appear to work. When I try to make this file I get the error:

```
root@61276deb5c1a:/code# make /data/interim/opt_smoothing.csv 
Determining optimal smoothing
Optimal smoothing calculation complete
&& python src/data/determine_optimal_smoothing.py && 
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected
make: *** [Makefile:10: /data/interim/opt_smoothing.csv] Error 2
```

When I include these 3 things on separate lines it works except the calculation complete message occurs before the script even finishes. What is the right way to chain these things together so they execute sequentially in the same shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use make's `info` function for this.  Make functions are run by **make**, not by the shell, as part of the expansion of the script in preparation to send it to the shell.  So, they are run before the shell is invoked.  Second, they expand to the empty string.

So for the recipe line:

```
    $(info foo) && python bar && $(info baz)
```

make will expand the line which causes `foo` and `baz` to be printed, then it will invoke the resulting string in the shell, which has `&&`, like this:

```
foo
baz
/bin/sh -c '&& python bar &&`
```

which is clearly invalid.

If you want to have the shell print things you have to use a shell command to do it, such as `echo`, not a make function.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. The example I was working off of chained 3 shell commands together, and I didn't realize the `info` function was fundamentally different.

Comment: Anything that begins with `$` in a recipe, unless it's escaped as `$$`, is always expanded by make before it is sent to the shell and the shell never sees it (it only sees whatever it expands to).